# Can I travel with cannabis-laced Vodka and Absinthe?

Tags: international-travel, legal, food-and-drink, alcohol, drugs

I am in Europe. Earlier I bought Vodka with little bit of cannabis, and Absinthe while I was in Prague, CZ. Now I am travelling internationally and was wondering if it is safe to carry one very small bottle of each of them.

Here are the photos of the drinks

[image]
[image]

**Update:** I am travelling from Germany to Russia with probably a layover somewhere in between.

Comment: So your question is whether you could get into trouble carrying illegal drugs (not withstanding their legal or quasi-legal status in some places) across international borders?

Comment: @ZachLipton: I'm not sure those would qualify as drugs; for example as far as I know, in Russia cannabis seeds are legal, but anything else cannabis-related is not.

Comment: Most of the cannabis spiced spirits sold in Europe contain only cannabis seeds, which have almost no THC content, so these beverages will not give you any intoxication except from the alcohol. Cannabis seeds are still considered a controlled substance or underly strict regulations and restrictions in most European countries, since they easily can be used to grow own cannabis plants. The alcohol is likely to permanently inactivate the germination capabilities of the seeds, but I assume that you may easily get in legal trouble in many countries if you are caught with these products.

Comment: Never mind, looked it up (absinthe legality)

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question, no it is not safe. Why? Safe means *protected from or not exposed to danger or risk*.

Although cannabis is given a pass in some places, it is generally illegal PLUS you are at the mercy of the interpretation of the law by the immigration and custom official who apprehends you. Regardless of whether you are ultimately exonerated or apprehended, the existence of risk means it is **NOT** safe.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned that you are travelling from Germany - this kind of vodka is not legal there. Here is [a news article in German](https://www.wochenblatt.de/polizei/regensburg/artikel/254358/cannabis-wodka-besitz-und-einfuhr-in-deutschland-verboten) - it's easy to buy it in the Czech Republic but it's not legal do import or possess it in Germany. If you get caught the vodka will be seized and you will be reported.

Comment: I would be more worried about what could happen in Russia, since OP is more likely to be searched there and the country's penal system is famously unfriendly.